# XSL nodeset: do not find child elements by name

Tags: xml, xslt

i am a beginner in xsl, so perhaps its a very easy question.
i have a xsl file where i want to find a specific value thats is defined in a param-object:

```
<xsl:param name="locales">
    <label name="testname"><locale name="de">german text</locale><locale name="en">english text</locale></label>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <topLevelElement xmlns="http://foo.bar.org">
        <xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($locales)/label[@name='testname']/locale[@name='en']"/>
    </topLevelElement>
</xsl:template>
```

I expected to get the value 'english text' because i want to find in the param `locales` a `label` with the name `testname`. There I want to find a `locale` with the name `en`. But it doesn't work.
 When I replace the name of the specific elements (label and locale) by a star, then it works:

```
<xsl:param name="locales">
    <label name="testname"><locale name="de">german text</locale><locale name="en">english text</locale></label>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <topLevelElement xmlns="http://foo.bar.org">
        <xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($locales)/*[@name='testname']/*[@name='en']"/>
    </topLevelElement>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't find the childs by its name? 
Thanks a lot!

**Edit**:
The code doesn't show the namespace (its interpreted by the browser i guess). It is without the brackets at the bginning and the end:

> xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" **xmlns="http://foo.bar.org"** **xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"** version="1.0"   xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/

Comment: Let me guess: There is an `xmlns="..."` default namespace defined in your XSLT file.

Comment: Yes i have. I have edited my question. So whats the problem with it? Does my label and locales now have another namespace so that i can't find them?

Comment: Where is the function deceleration 'ext:node-set(... )'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to fix it without changing the XPath is to change

```
<xsl:param name="locales">
    <label name="testname"><locale name="de">german text</locale><locale name="en">english text</locale></label>
</xsl:param>
```

to

```
<xsl:param name="locales" xmlns="">
    <label name="testname"><locale name="de">german text</locale><locale name="en">english text</locale></label>
</xsl:param>
```

Comment: thanks! thats an easy solution that works perfectly for me!

Comment: @Markus Consider the lower part of my answer as well. Namespaces and `node-set()` are not even necessary for this.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot tomalak. I will think about your solution. But i am a newbie in xsl so it takes some time to understand your solution completly ;) But your answer helps me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

So you have

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://foo.bar.org"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
>
```

and this defines a default namespace. Which means that *every XML element your XSLT program creates* (that isn't explicitly created with a namespace) *will be in that namespace*. This also applies to any element that you don't output.

And that means you cannot select these elements with "plain" XPath anymore, because plain XPath assumes that elements are in no namespace.

```
ext:node-set($locales)/label[@name='testname']/locale[@name='en']
```

looks for `<label>` elements that are in no namespace, and `<locale>` elements that are in no namespace. And the way to refer to a namespace in XPath is by using a prefix.

So you could give this namespace a prefix, just for internal handling.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://foo.bar.org"
    xmlns:foo="http://foo.bar.org"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
>
```

Here the `"http://foo.bar.org"` namespace is declared to be *default*, but also to have the prefix `foo`. Now you can do this:

```
ext:node-set($locales)/foo:label[@name='testname']/foo:locale[@name='en']
```

And things will start to work.

---

Personally, I would not use `<xsl:param>` for what you are doing. I would set up a supplementary XML document that has no namespaces, call it `locales.xml`, and then do:

```
<!-- top-level -->
<xsl:variable name="locales" select="document('locales.xml')" />

<!-- ...later -->
<xsl:value-of select="$locales/*/label[@name='testname']/locale[@name='en']" />
```

This way neither helper namespaces nor `ext:node-set()` are required, and you have increased modularity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your information! it helped me a lot. I will consider your suggestion to use a supplementary XML file.